# SAP OData Call with Reactive WebClient - "/" escaping

Tags: url, encoding, odata, spring-webclient

Currently I am working on an integration development with SAP using OData service. My client application is based on JAVA 8 Spring.

**Problem:**

From my client application, when I do a GET using spring reactive webclient – SAP is not able to process the request. But when I use the same URL in  Firefox-REST client I am getting proper response. This is only happening when we have "/" in some of values of URL.

Here is my URL.

http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='/ON/CLOUD')/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled

The field DATA='/ON/CLOUD' is causing trouble here. (Please note that when I don’t use "/" everything works just fine)

I tried this by manually escaping the "/": - this is working fine from REST client
http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='%2FON%2FCLOUD')/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled

But when I do GET from my java client with above URL, SAP is complaining Malformed URL. When I checked the logs in SAP, for some reason my client program making GET call with below URL
http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='%252FON%252FCLOUD')/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled

So '%2FON%2FCLOUD' converted to '%252FON%252FCLOUD' in the GET call.

***I would like to escape '%' and use URL whatever I sent. Could you please  help me where I can fix this?***

Here is the code I am using at the moment.

url – is my URL

```
{
        Mono<String> mono;
            mono = webClient().get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .exchange()
                    .doOnError(e -> { throw new HttpException("Error executing GET request", e); } )
                    .doOnSuccess(onSuccess -> res = onSuccess)
                    .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
        String body = mono.block();
        log.debug("Response object: {}", res);
        log.info("Get returned: {}", body);
        checkClientResponseCode(res, HttpStatus.OK, body);
        return body;

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

More information:

Here is the http trace of the JAVA client:

GET sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='%25F2ON%25F2CLOUD')/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.15.RELEASE
Host: hostname:port
accept-encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic AuthorizationKey==

I am actually sending below URL to Spring WebClient
sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='%2F2ON%2F2CLOUD')/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled

My spring version: springBootVersion = '2.0.9.RELEASE'

My SAP Version: SAP FPSL Release 753

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Could you do an HTTP trace, so that to see if the URI is incorrectly transformed by Spring Framework WebClient, or incorrectly parsed by SAP. What SAP softwware do you use, and what are Spring Framework and SAP versions?

Comment: Hello Sandra: I have updated the issue with further details. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: So, culprit is Spring? It should not percent-encode already-percent-encoded characters. I think it's best to [file a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot#reporting-issues). Maybe one workaround is to split yourself the URL into path and query string: `wC = webClient.create( "http://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/Service/Set(RUNTYPE='TEST',DATA='%2FON%2FCLOUD')" )` and `wC.get( ).uri( "/?sap-client=XXX&spnego=disabled" )`. NB: in your answer, you made "copy/paste" errors (`%25F2` and `%2F2` instead of `%252F`), so I don't know if the rest of information is reliable or not...